# What exactly does this error code mean in Blue Screen of Death

Tags: windows-xp, bsod

I got an old PC of six years old. It's running XP SP2.
Recently, when I was doing some graphics editing, 
the screen turned into BSOD with some error code showing at the bottom of the screen:

Stop: 0X0000000000A (0X0FB38EC2, ...)

I have no clue what this code is.
Where can I find some decription in detail corresponding to this error code?
Could you help me out please?

[image]

Comment: 1) the people at SuperUser might help you better; 2) this looks like a driver bug.

Comment: Did you Google this? The IRQL error is quite common...

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff560129(VS.85).aspx

Answer (score 2):

This most likely (but not always) means faulty memory.

I would use [Memtest86+](http://www.memtest.org) and leave it running for at least 48 hours to make sure you have no problems.

Answer (score 1):

I've had this issue before after swapping the boot order of my HDDs on an older system.  XP was installed on an IDE disk and I had linux installed on a second-hand SCSI drive.

If you've recently installed any new hardware or recently installed a second OS, or made changes to your partitions, try to undo those changes.

Otherwise, try tapping F8 during boot until you get the safe mode menu, select "Last known good configuration", and hit enter.

If that doesn't work, try the Memtest86+ reccomended by Wil, and if it finds no problems, boot the XP install disc and re-install.  You don't need to reformat or anything, just do a repair or in-place upgrade install.  If it won't install because of a service pack you have installed, you'll need to slipstream that onto the XP disc using [nLite](http://nliteos.com).